# Text Overlapping the Image - Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

So I am learning to use bootstrap and I can't figure out why my text keeps overlapping the image. After messing around a bit I found that It has something to do with the bootstrap grid system or how I am using the "col" inside of the row. The image was smaller and the text was right next to the image but after implementing bootstrap it just overlaps with the image.
Below is the screenshot of the actual problem and HTML code. [This shows how the text is overlapping the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Htg.jpg)

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ0Om.png)

Comment: Hi Cloudcoder. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, could you paste your code directly into question, so that it could be indexed by google and easier to find? I.e. could you please replace screenshot of code with code ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other styling? I replicated your code in [this pen](https://codepen.io/dnrm/pen/BaWvjYg)

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Sample website</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nobis exercitationem suscipit omnis dolores, ullam blanditiis quo eum, pariatur labore consequatur, est nulla beatae quae. Ullam fuga facilis aliquid animi.</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Hai</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

and the text doesn't overlap the image. Also, try to use bootstrap through the CDN.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css
(Import both CSS and JS bundle)